# Unable to connect remotely to a Debian server through Remote Desktop/Remmina/VNC from Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect remotely to a Debian server from my Debian client. However, neither Remmina nor VNC work. In fact, Remmina shows the following information:

```
Reconnection in progress
```

When I try to connect remotely from my Windows machine or my colleague's Ubuntu, I don't face any problems. So the issue seems to be with the client Debian.

I haven't been able to find any useful information for solving this issue. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: First, verify that the Debian server is actually receiving the incoming connection, either by looking at the relevant logs or by monitoring the network traffic server-side with `tcpdump`, Wireshark or similar. Neither VNC nor Remote Desktop are enabled by default on a Debian server; have you actually enabled either of them? A server system might not have a local GUI running at all, so a VNC service that enables sharing of an existing GUI session won't work; for server use, you'll need a VNC server that creates its own session, like `tigervnc-standalone-server` package in Debian 10.

Comment: @telcoM thank you for providing potential solutions. The Debian server is running Jessie and has both RDP and VNC enables. In fact, I can boot to Windows and connect to the server through RDP. However, on the same machine, when I boot to Debian, I can't connect to the server either through RDP or VNC. Additionally, when I run `telnet ip 9501` on my local machine, I don't get any response from the server.

Comment: If you aren't even getting a "connection refused" message from your `telnet` test, but the `telnet` command just hangs until the connection times out, it sounds like a possible firewall/`iptables` issue. So the next question might be, "which software firewall configuration solution you're using in the Debian client and how is it configured?"

Comment: @telcoM I haven't set up any firewall. The `iptables -L` shows three empty sections.

Answer (score -1):

I have very similar issues.
I can rdp in to any windows box from my Debian 10 desktop
ditto from any windows or android device to a windows device or my Debian 10 desktop, or my raspberry pi.
However, I can not rdp in to my pi from the Debian 10 desktop it simply shuts/crashes out of the remote connection client. I have tried several and none of them now work.
This used to work on the Debian desktop until upgrading it from 9.x to 10.x
The difference for me is I can ssh in to the pi, start vncserver and then connect using the same clients but set up for vnc rather than rdp on the desktop.

The only issues with using a client from Android is the MS one needs to be quite an old version to work with the pi and have the connection set not to use a saved user and password but to ask each time.  Trying the same on the Debian desktop made no difference it still crashes out.
As vnc works it still gives me a workable method. I can either start vnc through ssh or enable X forwarding and have the choice of a gui program or using the terminal console.

Thus the only issue with over 20 assorted devices is between a Debian desktop computer and a raspberry pi also running Debian but an earlier release ie < 10.x

Comment: indeed I have a centos 7 setup on external hard drive on my windows desktop.  The Debian 10 can not connect over rdp to the centos 7 using xrdp.  Or vice versa the centos can not connect to the Debian 10, or my pi.  However they can all connect to windows pc's and they can all connect to either of them. So there does appear to be an issue with the gnu/linux clients connecting to a server running xrdp!